# Updating table using WHERE condition from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to use the following SQL:

```
  UPDATE `vocabulary` 
  SET `wordEN` = `wordES` 
  WHERE `vocabulary`.`lessonID` = `lessons`.`id` 
  AND `lessons`.`courseID` = 2
```

But I get the following error:

> 1054 - Unknown column 'lessons.id' in 'where clause'

Is there anyway to do this within MYSQL? Maybe having a query within a query or something?

Comment: The error says lessons.id is unknown. That means it does not exist or your query can't see it. Did you check to see if there was a table called lessons? If so, is there an id column in the lessons table? If you answered yes to both, then you need to join tables vocabulary and lessons together to see lessons.id. Hence the answer below where someone suggested to join the two tables together to see lessons.id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you want `update` with `join`.  This may be the query you are looking for:

```
UPDATE vocabulary v join
       lessons l
       on v.lessonID = l.id and
          l.courseID = 2
     SET v.wordEN = v.wordES;
```

EDIT:

This may also work:

```
UPDATE vocabulary v
   SET v.wordEN = v.wordES
   where v.lessonId in (select id from lessons l where l.courseID = 2);
```

Comment: Hi both wordEN and wordES are in the vocabulary table, just I only want to update where lessons.level is 2

Comment: lessons.level is not in your example query nor in your question.